# error during execution of trigger : ORA-06502: PL/SQL numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

when I try to insert in the data table, I get this"numeric or value error: character to number conversion error" 
This is my trigger :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_ON_TEMP 
BEFORE INSERT ON DATA 
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    CURSOR ERR_MSG_CURSOR IS
    SELECT ERROR_MSG FROM REFERENTIEL;
    codeERR VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
    OPEN ERR_MSG_CURSOR; ****
    LOOP
        FETCH ERR_MSG_CURSOR INTO codeERR;
            if (:new.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+codeERR+'%') THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I got here:'||:new.DESCRIPTION);
             END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ERR_MSG_CURSOR;
END;
```

The error is occuring on the line with ****. I'm not quite too sure as to what is causing this error, any help?

Comment: Change `'%'+codeERR+'%'` to `'%'||codeERR||'%'`.

Comment: You also have an infinite loop there. Add 'EXIT WHEN ERR_MSG_CURSOR%NOTFOUND' right after the FETCH statement.

Comment: What is the purpose of this trigger? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Btw: you don't need a cursor to begin with, a `for coderr in (select ... )` would be more efficient, see e.g. the [example in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-25917214-FD91-499D-AB39-CE21484AB167)